# New figure environment

Tags: floats, environments

I am writing my PhD thesis. In my manuscript I have Figures in the text and Photographic plates (a figure of figures) in the annexes. The two elements are different and I would like create a new environment of Plate that follows the same structure of the Figure environment. Where can I find the Figure environment to modify it?

The new environment table should have exactly the same structure than the figure environment but replacing the word figure by the word Planche (in French).

Comment: Please comment concerning whether you also need to create a list of figures that will be separate from the list of planche's, as this would complicate (I imagine) the answer. Presumably, you would want a separate counter as well.

Answer (score 34):

There is now a new dedicated package [`newfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) which allows the definition of new floats. It does this in the same format like the original floats `figure` and `table` without forcing a specific format, like the `float` package does.

The `newfloat` package is part of the `caption` bundle and was extracted from the related code of the `caption` package by its author (on my request).

An example of define a new floating environment named `scheme` is:

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=los,
    listname={List of Schemes},
    name=Scheme,
    placement=tbhp,
    within=section,
]{scheme}
```

Comment: Maybe you could include the meaning of those options? (For example how is listname used?)

Comment: I am getting a weird numbering. I thought the "scheme" environment would get its own numbering. I.e. I want the first scheme to get the number 1. etc... Instead the section number seems to be used.

Comment: Okay the answer seems to be to not use within=...

Answer (score 19):

To do this in the raw, use the [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) or [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) packages.

```
\newfloat{plate}{tbp}{lop}
```

Alternatively, the [`trivfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/trivfloat) package aims to wrap up the complexities of `float(row)` so that you only have to do

```
\usepackage{trivfloat}
\trivfloat{plate}
```

(Note: I wrote `trivfloat`.)

As you might guess, `trivfloat` makes things easy but at the cost of flexibility. If you want full control over the process, use `float` (or `floatrow`).

Comment: One drawback of `float` IMHO is that it forces a certain style. Apparently it collects the content of the float in a box and places the caption afterwards (which got only stored by `\caption`). You loose the possibility to place multiple entries with own captions in one floats using `minipage`s etc.

Answer (score 17):

The »[caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)« package also masters to create new float environments with corresponding lists.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\DeclareCaptionType[fileext=los,placement={!ht}]{scheme}

\begin{document}
  \listofschemes

  \bigskip
  \blindtext

  \begin{scheme}
    \centering
    \rule{0.75\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
    \caption{Dummy scheme}\label{sch:dummy}
  \end{scheme}

  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

Nowadays the »[newfloat](http://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat)« package (as part of the »caption« bundle) package is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to look at the `float` package, which allows you to define and set up new floats with quite simple commands.

In your preamble: `\usepackage{float}`

Then, you define new floats using the following syntax:

```
\newfloat{<type>}{<placement>}{<ext>}[<within>]
```

> `<type>` is the ‘type’ of the new class of floats, like `program` or
>   `algorithm`. After the appropriate `\newfloat`, commands like
>   `\begin{program}` or `\end{algorithm*}` will be available.
>   `<placement>` gives the default placement parameters for this class of
>   floats. The placement parameters are the same as in standard LATEX,
>   i.e., t, b, p and h for ‘top’, ‘bottom’, ‘page’ and ‘here’,
>   respectively. When LATEX writes the captions to an auxiliary file for
>   the list of figures (or whatever), it’ll use the job name followed by
>   `<ext>` as a file name. Finally, the optional argument `<within>`
>   determines whether floats of this class will be numbered within some
>   sectional unit of the document. For example, if `<within>=chapter`, the
>   floats will be numbered within chapters. (Source: [package documentation](http://ftp.fagskolen.gjovik.no/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf))

Thus, you could do something like

```
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{Planche}{hbtp}{lop}[section]

...

\begin{Planche}
...
\end{Planche}
```

There are many more configuration options, so please go to the [documentation](http://ftp.fagskolen.gjovik.no/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf) and see what you can do! =)

Answer (score 5):

Since there aren't enough possibilities (and I haven't praised KOMA-Script today), yet, let me present another possibility. The package `tocbasic` (which is part of the [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle and already loaded if you happen to use a KOMA class) let's you define new floating environments through its command

```
\DeclareNewTOC[<options>]{<extension>}
```

It is explained in detail in the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/scrguien.pdf). Here is an example how one could use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=plate,%
  types=plates,% used in the \listof.. command
  float,% define a floating environment
  floattype=4,% see below
  name=Planche,%
  listname={Table des planches}%
]{lop}

% About the `floattype' option:
% The numerical float type of the defined floats. Float types with common bits
% cannot be reordered. At the standard classes figures has float type 1 and tables
% has floatype 2. If no float type was given, 16 will be used.

\begin{document}

\listofplates

\begin{plate}
 whatever
 \caption{a caption}
\end{plate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried this nifty solution out. It has the advantage, e.g. over `trivfloat`, that a `KOMA-Script`-option such as `list=nochaptergap` was automatically applied to the newly-declared list. This was especially useful to achieve a coherent format with different lists in one document.