# Create two sets of caption labels

Tags: captions

I would like to create two sets of caption labels in latex, but research online has not yielded any satisfactory solution. I was wondering if anyone can provide help.

More specifically, I have many images to insert into a paper that need to be sorted. Some will be labeled normally (i.e. Figure 1, Figure 2, etc.). However, there is another set I would like to name sequentially in a different format (i.e. Plate 1, Plate 2, etc.). I am using `\includegraphics` in the `float` environment for inserting images. However, I am open to any adjustments.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're already using the `float` package, then it's easy to set up a new kind of float for your Plate images:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% for dummy text
\newfloat{plate}{pb}{plt} % second argument should be {htbp} in your actual document
\floatname{plate}{Plate}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listof{plate}{List of Plates}
\section{A section}
\kant[1-2]
\begin{figure}[bp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{fig}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\kant[2]
\begin{plate}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3in]{plate}
  \caption{A plate}
\end{plate}
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you also want to use the `caption` package to manage caption formatting, you can achieve the same result with the `newfloat` package, which is more compatible with `caption`.  The code is almost the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% for dummy text
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{plate}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listofplates
\section{A section}
\kant[1-2]
\begin{figure}[bp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{fig}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\kant[2]
\begin{plate}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3in]{plate}
  \caption{A plate}
\end{plate}
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another variation using the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) package, borrowing from [New figure environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6478/new-figure-environment)

It creates a file `\jobname.lop` that stores a list of the `plate`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionType[fileext=lop,placement={!ht}]{plate}

\begin{document}
\listofplates

\begin{plate}
    \centering
    \rule{0.75\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
    \caption{My plate caption}
    \label{plate:mylabel}
\end{plate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't really documented in the main `caption` documentation; it's implemented in the `caption` kernel by loading the `newfloat` package.

Comment: `\DeclareCaptionType` was implemented in the `caption` package and documented in its documentation in the past, but was outsourced to the new `newfloat` package so this functionality is available now for people who don't want to use or can't use the `caption` package, too. (But using `\DeclareCaptionType` is still ok, I will keep that supported for compatibility reasons.)