# Copying a float environment with modified name and float counter

Tags: floats

Is it possible to copy a float environment, such as e.g. the figure environment, to create a new environment, with identical properties except for the name (e.g. create a 'Ancillary Figure' instead of 'Figure' name) and float-counter?

In short, I would like to have a situation where I could have two distinct but concurrent figure-environments, one for "primary" figures and one for "auxiliary/ancillary" figures.

I expect that the [float](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/float?lang=en) package would be handy here, but cannot see how to copy an environment.

Comment: Basically it comes down to `float` package usage, with `\newfloat` and some configuration of the caption, that should be done with `caption` package, of course. There's also a `\newfloat` package, by the same author as `caption`. Copying is more than just renaming the macro names ;-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! I believe your question is answered here: [New figure environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6478/). If that's the case we'll probably close your question as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Indeed, this answers my question fully; if you would close the question as a duplicate, I would appreciate. Thanks to both of you for the help!