# How to insert a JPEG image but have the label call it a 'scheme'?

Tags: floats, labels

I have a `.jpg` image in my LaTeX document I want to be labelled as "Scheme x" rather than "Fig. x". Is it possible to change the label?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6478/15925 help?

Answer (score 3):

With the package `chemstyle` you can get a "Scheme" instead of a "Figure". I think in the command `\label{xxx:test}` you can write for xxx what ever you want.

UPDATE: You could also use a .jpg instead of a .pdf in my example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.pdf}
    \caption{Test.}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Output of my example (pdflatex compiler): 
[image: Output of my example (pdflatex compiler)]

Comment: Thanks Vincent, unfortuantely when I do this I get the error message saying "environment scheme undefined"

Comment: \renewcommand*{\schemename}{Scheme}

Comment: what about using that command?

Comment: Or you need to install the package first an your local computer? Sorry here ends my knowledge

Comment: @rleve Did you add \usepackage{chemstyle}? Vincent's code worked fine when I tested.