# Toc of pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, table-of-contents

I have charts like this:

```
% !TeX root=thesis.tex
\begin{figure}
        \centering
\fbox{  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    y tick  label  style={
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep= },
    xlabel=\rl{توان مصرف شده بر حسب کیلووات},
    ylabel=\rl{تعداد ماشین‌های مجازی},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    xbar=5pt,
    ymax=270,ymin=80,
          bar width=0.9em,
    height=6cm,width=12cm,
                nodes near coords,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(0.26,100) (0.33,150) 
        (0.45,200) (0.62,250)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(0.25,100) (0.31,150)
         (0.42,200) (0.61,250)};

\legend{ B\_M,S\_S}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{مقایسه مصرف انرژی با سیاست
\lr{MMT}
}
\label{ch1}
\end{figure}
```

How I can have a list of these charts? I would like a "toc of charts" or something?

Comment: `\listoffigures`?

Comment: Have a look for `DeclareNewTOC` on this site.

Comment: `tocloft` and its \newlistof macro..., for example

Comment: @TorbjørnT. no I want list of my charts be seperate from list of figures
@Johannes_B which site?
@ChristianHupfer tnx I`ll duck that

Comment: You can only ping one user per comment. @Johannes_B meant *this* site (tex.stackexchange) -- there is a search box in the top right.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6478/new-figure-environment/

Comment: @samcarter yes it is, i didnt knew what I must search, tnx