# Different numbering of Figure environment with separate captions

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to include figures and application snippets in my report. Both of them are supplied as png and in Figure environment. While I know how to rename the entire Figure environment, is there any way to separate them, so I can have separate numbering for Figure environment, such as Figure.1 and Snippet.1.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [New figure environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6478/5764); [Defining a new type of floating environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95631/5764)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my question can be dealt with newfloat package. I am still working through understanding how that works, but I believe the question is answered.