# How to replace "figure" in \begin{figure}?

Tags: floats

In many journal articles it is customary to refer to a "figure", and label it as Figure 1 etc. How do we use an alternate description? What if you want to call it say Painting 1 or Construction 1 instead of Figure 1?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}   
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4in]{Example.eps}
\caption {Draw line $L$.}
\label{fig:Euclid}
\end{figure}

% instead would like to use something like below
\begin{construction]}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4in]{Example.eps}
\caption {Draw line $L$.}
\label{cons:Euclid}
\end{construction}
%

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can also create new float types using the newfloat or float packages.  Then you can still use figure as figure.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [New figure environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6478/5764); [Defining a new type of floating environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95631/5764)

Comment: I assume you want to create a new floating environment, not just use `figure` with an alternative label/caption, right?

Comment: @Werner At this point I am not sure what is the right approach for me. What David mentioned below is working. Now I realize if I have both Figures and Paintings then it becomes more complicated and I guess John Kormylo answer above, regarding "new float", or something similar will be needed.

Comment: @Maesumi: The linked posts in my comment above provide all the tools/options you need to create a new float type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\renewcommand\figurename{Painting}`