Can you show me how to make a custom float for schemes in my RSC journal manuscript following their template?
I'm really new to Latex thinking this could solve my issues with editing manuscript in Word. I would like to know if someone worked with RSC latex templates before. And if you did, can you show me how you made your own float for schemes (which are numbered differently from tables and figures). If you did not, can you help me anyways? This is how RSC formatted their figure float and I could not get my head wrapped around it.
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,9pt]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.785cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,font={stretch=1.125,small,sf},labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fnpos}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
  \renewcommand{\refname}{Notes and references}
}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{droidsans}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%Please don't disable any packages in the preamble, as this may cause the template to display incorrectly.%%%
\usepackage{epstopdf}%This line makes .eps figures into .pdf - please comment out if not required.
\definecolor{cream}{RGB}{222,217,201}


.........

%%%FIGURE SETUP - please do not change any commands within this section%%%
\makeatletter 
\newlength{\figrulesep} 
\setlength{\figrulesep}{0.5\textfloatsep} 

\newcommand{\topfigrule}{\vspace*{-1pt}% 
\noindent{\color{cream}\rule[-\figrulesep]{\columnwidth}{1.5pt}} }

\newcommand{\botfigrule}{\vspace*{-2pt}% 
\noindent{\color{cream}\rule[\figrulesep]{\columnwidth}{1.5pt}} }

\newcommand{\dblfigrule}{\vspace*{-1pt}% 
\noindent{\color{cream}\rule[-\figrulesep]{\textwidth}{1.5pt}} }

\makeatother
%%%END OF FIGURE SETUP%%%

.....

    \begin{figure*}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=8cm]{Schemes_Figures/Scheme1.png}
        \caption{Possible interaction of MUDA-AuNP (11-mercaptoundecanoic acid functionalized gold nanoparticles) and NHS-AuNP (NHS-ester capped MUDA-AuNP) towards spermine.}
        \label{figure:Scheme 1}
    \end{figure*}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a complete short TeX code? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

You are ment to use the template as-is and only edi tin your text - why are you trying to alter the numbering?

I guess I just need a separate numbering for schemes. These templates can sometimes be too limiting.

Trying this
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57055
There is now a new dedicated package newfloat which allows the definition of new floats. It does this in the same format like the original floats figure and table without forcing a specific format, like the float package does.
The newfloat package is part of the caption bundle and was extracted from the related code of the caption package by its author (on my request).
An example of define a new floating environment named scheme is:
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=los,
    listname={List of Schemes},
    name=Scheme,
    placement=tbhp,
    within=section,
]{scheme}

